# /dev/ttyS0 can't be opened in Qemu

Tags: filesystems, arm, qemu, buildroot

I am working with QEMU 1.1.0, emulating Versatile Express board with ARM Cortex-A9. I have managed to launch simple "Hello World" example following this instructions:

http://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/compile-linux-kernel-3-2-for-arm-and-emulate-with-qemu/

but now I want to create filesystem by myself.

I decided to use buildroot, version 2012.05. and I've configured it to create toolchain, kernel and filesystem image for ARM Cortex-A9 target.

Kernel is of version 3.3.7 and for the filesystem I've selected to be cpio, non-compressed. The initrd argument in call to qemu-system-arm is pointing to

**/output/images/rootfs.cpio**

When I launch QEMU kernel boots, but then I get this message:

**Initializing random number generator... done.**

**Starting network...**

**can't open /dev/ttyS0: No such device or address**

**can't open /dev/ttyS0: No such device or address**

**can't open /dev/ttyS0: No such device or address**

**...**

All I can do is to terminate QEMU.

I have checked the contents of rootfs.cpio like this:

cpio -t < rootfs.cpio

and saw that there is /dev/ttyS0.

Have I missed something in configuring the filesystem? Or should I use filesystem in

**/output/target**

to somehow create device(s) there (Buildroot does not do that), and then rebuild the filesystem?

I'm new to Buildroot, so any hint or suggestion is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Extract rootfs and type ls -all `/dev/ttyS0` and check it's `major` and `minor` number. Because if your major number is not the required one then it will not invoke respective kernel functionality and in that case it will only be a junk character device.

Also can you post the whole log file (copy all those dmesg and post those somewhere and give link here.)

And if you are sure that /dev/ttyS0 is there then do the following steps :

- extract(unpack using cpio) rootfs
- find out which init file kernel is using as parent process. If you are lucky then it would be lying in root directory. named `init` or `initrc`
- open `init` file in your favorite editor.
- starting few lines of your init would be like

  ::respawn:/sbin/getty -L 38400 tty1
  ::respawn:/sbin/getty -L 38400 tty2
  ::respawn:/sbin/getty -L 38400 tty3
  ::respawn:/sbin/getty -L 38400 tty4
- add `::respawn:/sbin/ls -all /dev`  and save the file. (We have added list command to see what is there inside /dev directory)
- reboot your system and check the dmesg. See if `/dev/ttyS0` is really missing ?

Comment: what I can do if no `tty` in `/dev` directory ?